# PHP: searching id tags @ .html file

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, array-key

I have this simple code I want to search some tags on a .html file but I get some error I'm just new to php and I encounter **'preg_match'** command.

here's my simple code:

```
<?php
$data['id="test"'] = 'A';

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

if(preg_match(array_keys($data), $html)) 
{
    echo 'FOUND';
}
else
{
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
}
?>
```

it gives me an error **Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in**

the code above searches in *test.html* if **"id=test"** test exist in the *test.html* file.

Comment: Use an HTML parser, like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `array_keys($data)` gives back an array with 1 element: `['id="test"']`... that is not a string

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Did you try *any* debugging? You should at least try `var_dump(array_keys($data))` to test your assumption; you'd find that it is indeed returning an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can see that the preg_match needs the first parameter to be a string

```
int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

and that array_keys return value is "array"

```
array array_keys ( array $array [, mixed $search_value = NULL [, bool $strict = false ]] )
```

so you get "preg_match() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

try this :

```
$data[] = 'id="test"';
$data[] = 'id="test2"';
$data[] = 'id="test3"';
$html = file_get_contents('test.html');
foreach ($data as $search){
 if (strpos($html , $search) !== FALSE)
    echo 'FOUND';
 else
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
}
```

Comment: i like your idea but I need **$data['id=test']** so I can used array_keys and on array_values I can put something.

Comment: then it will look like this : `$data['id="test"'] = 'A'; foreach ($data as $search => $value).......`

Answer (score 1):

at a minimum, you need to do this:

```
<?php
$data['id="test"'] = 'A';
$data=array_keys($data);
$data = preg_quote($data[0],"'");

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

if(preg_match('~'.$data.'~', $html)) 
{
    echo 'FOUND';
}
else
{
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
}
?>
```

However.. there are many ways this could be optimized, if you are willing/able to refactor the structure of `$data`

also note that this will only look for an exact match. It will not match if `"test"` is wrapped in single quotes, or if there are spaces between `id` and `"test"` etc..

in short, the way you have it now, you may as well just use `strpos`

Comment: can you explain what **$data = preg_quote($data[0],"'");** what is the **$data[0]**?

Comment: `preg_quote` escapes anything in `$data` that is a special symbol to `preg_match`.  About `$data[0]` - as others have mentioned, `array_keys` returns an **array**, but `preg_match` expects a **string** value.  `$data[0]` references the first element in the `$data` array, which is a **string** value containing your value `id="test"`

Comment: $data[0] will just find the 1st element in array so if I add more element in array I will difine them again and again?

Comment: well, yes. Like I said, *at a minimum* you need to do what I showed, to fix the code you posted. I then followed it up by telling you that there are better ways to structure your data (e.g. the one suggested by DimaK)

Comment: @Detention it would greatly benefit you to take a step back and spend an hour or two learning the basic syntax ;) Also, http://www.php.net has online documentation for the functions etc. and they make it super easy to find an entry. For example you can just go to http://www.php.net/array_keys and it will take you to the `array_keys` entry where it shows expected syntax, return type, etc..